# Начал учить python. В чём я ошибаюсь?

Tags: python

```
# Температура

t = int(input('Введите число: '))

if t < -4:
    print("морозно")

elif t < 0 and >= -4:
    print('холодно')

elif t >= 0 and < 12:
    print('прохладно')

elif t >= 12 and < 27:
    print('тепло')

elif t >= 27:
    print('жарко')
```

Comment: Синтаксис оператора and — `выражение and выражение`. Слева вы пишите выражение `t < 0` и оно правильное, а справа вы пишете `>= -4` и оно неправильное, потому что не указано к чему относится `>=`

Comment: можно же и без `and` - `-4 <= t < 0`

Answer (score 0):

После and тоже нужно переменную указывать которую сравниваете

```
t = int(input('Введите число: '))

if t < -4:
    print("морозно")

elif t < 0 and t >= -4:
    print('холодно')

elif t >= 0 and t < 12:
    print('прохладно')

elif t >= 12 and t < 27:
    print('тепло')

elif t >= 27:
    print('жарко')
```